# IPTables nat is throttling TCP SYN when hitting several rules

Tags: iptables, nat

Linux kernel is 4.9.17-8.31

I am opening up many external ports that map onto a single internal port. The reason is that each customer group gets there own port, this allows upstream accounting with tc.

Rules look something like this:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --match multiport --dports 3000,3032,3064,3096,3128,3160,3192,3224,3256,3288 -j REDIRECT --to-port 54321
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --match multiport --dports 3330,3352,3384,3416,3448,3480,3512,3544,3576,3608 -j REDIRECT --to-port 54321
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --match multiport --dports 3640,3672,3704,3736,3768,3800,3832,3864,3896,3928 -j REDIRECT --to-port 54321
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --match multiport --dports 3960,3992,3024,3056,3088,3113,3152,3184,3216,3248 -j REDIRECT --to-port 54321`

If I test 400 connections hitting one of these rules all the connections happen cleanly.

If I test 100 connections hitting each of the 4 rule lines I see timeouts and re-transmissions of the TCP SYN packets, I can tcpdump capture the TCP SYN is arriving, but not responded to, no TCP SYN ACK response.

I cannot find a drop or error point and all connections hitting one rule is very solid.  In my test scenarios all 400 connections are from a single host,  unsure if problem exists in a more real world scenario where connections will be coming from multiple hosts.

For testing purposes I have de-configured tc and can reproduce errors with iptables alone.

Interested to see if this behavior has been observed in the past.

Comment: I understand that the rules are not an exact copy of the ones you use, but you should provide a functional sample.  These are invalid iptables rules.

Comment: Hi Julie thank you for looking at this.
Here is the same rules mapping to port 22:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --match multiport --dports 3000,3032,<snip> -j REDIRECT --to-port 22
Now test by ssh to port 3000 you can see the single stat increment in the rule containing port 3000
iptables -t nat -n -v -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1    52 REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 3000,<snip> redir ports 22

Comment: When you say connections hitting those four rules, do you mean that they get evaluated and ignored or they match?  There can only be a single match as it will return after.

Comment: I an testing w/ 400 connections. All 400 connections match 1 rule and connection performance is good.  4x100 connections each matching 1 of the 4 rules. connection performance degrades.  Nothing else changes other then the dest port.

Comment: Can you lay out a simple but complete test plan so that someone like me could blindly test it?  I'm also curious to know why you don't simply DNAT to the right port and if it does the same thing.

Comment: Have ~40 users groups of a service. Want fairness across groups. Using ingress and egress tc to shape 40 HTBs.  Give each group a different port to access service.  Then use iptables to nat the user group ports onto the service port.  On average there is 10 users per groups so ~400 users.  I notices slow connection rate when testing 400 connections using all 40 ports.  Started reducing test be removing traffic shaping. Then simplifying ports being accessed.  Found problem was related to having several different nat rules being accessed at same time

Comment: Steps to reproduce.  Use rules like in original ticket, with --to-port being something that can handle all the connections like port 80.  open 400 connections to one port, for example  3000, and "watch iptables -t nat -n -v -L" you will see 400 connections go through in 1 to 2 seconds.  Then redo the test with 100 connections going to each of the 4 rule lines, for example ports 3000, 3330, 3640, and 3960.  You will see must lines stats go to 100, but 1 or 2 will take ~10 sec.  tcpdump shows TCP SYN timeout and retransmission.

Comment: Also I do not think DNAT is the correct choice.  I am not directing traffic to another host, simple directing traffic to another port on the localhost.  I believe REDIRECT is the correct rule.